# what is current_task on linux i686?

Tags: linux, module, task, proc

i am analysis linux moudule on ida pro. but i don't know current_task in source. this moudule is proc program and to run linux command on virtual address that you set

it's one part of source:

```
  v0 = mcount();
  v1 = v0;
  v2 = v0 >> 30;
```

> v3 = *(_DWORD *)(*(_DWORD *)(__readfsdword((signed
>   __int32)&current_task) + 468) + 36);

```
  v4 = *(_DWORD *)(v3 + 8 * (v0 >> 30));
  v5 = *(_DWORD *)(v3 + 8 * v2 + 4);
  if ( v4 & 1 )
  {
    v6 = *(_DWORD *)(((v1 & 0x3FE00000) >> 18) + (v4 & 0xFFFFF000) - 0x40000000);
    if ( v6 & 1 )
    {
      if ( v6 & 0x80 )
      {
        v9 = v1;
        printk("2MB page\n");
        result = v9 & 0x7FFFF | v6 & 0xFFF80000;
      }
      else
      {
        v10 = v1;
        v7 = get_pte_entry();
        if ( v7 & 1 )
        {
          result = v10 & 0xFFF | v7 & 0xFFFFF000;
        }
        else
        {
          printk("PT64 entry not present %x\n");
          result = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      printk("PD64 entry not present %x\n");
      result = 0;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printk("PAE entry not present %x\n");
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

it's runing display:
[runing display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlTij.png)

do you know current_task?

Comment: Take a look in `./arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c`

Answer (score 0):

You are/were working on the softmmu challenge at pwnable.kr.

The current_task you are looking for is the pointer to "struct task_struct" that is unique to the current running process (in your case 'cat' for the screenshot you show). However this is supposed to be hidden from user land applications, it is a critical struct inside the kernel. You'll probably need to find a way to leak this information. If you can leak the thread_info, it has a pointer to the task you need. If you have arbitrary read/write, you would be able to update the effective credentials for the task and gain root.

Here is a good page describing the relationship between thread_info and task_struct. 
http://hypervsir.blogspot.com/2014/10/in-linux-kernel-threadinfo-is-small-cpu.html